# Is there an API to tell which feature is currently being a target of "identify" tool?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-3

I want to make a plugin that calculates some property of a selected feature.
I can use "select feature" tool and then use

```
l=iface.layerTreeView().selectedLayers()[0]
f=list(l.getSelectedFeatures())[0]
```

to access it.
However, when I am picking my feature I need to see its attributes, easiest is to use "identify" function for this. So I would like to click on a feature with "identify" tool and if the attributes are to my liking, I want to run my script without "selecting" this feature again.

Comment: check this https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/303537/49538 and https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/260214/49538